# Save captured image to SDcard

Tags: android

i want to save captured `image` from `camera` to `extSdcard` , but the problem  the `images` have stored in the `internal memory` of my phone with `android 4.4.4(kitkat)` and `android 5.1.1` but with `android 4.2` the image have stored in the `extsdcard` , have you any idea about this please ?

Comment: Since android 4.4 you are not allowed to write to secondary/removable storage.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html

Comment: there is no solution for this   !   i want to store many pictures and the internal memory is not a solution for this  !

Comment: Write it to your app specific folder in secondary storage. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Document](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/)

> Apps must not be allowed to write to secondary external storage
>   devices, except in their package-specific

You can write to the app specific folder on `primary external storage` i.e. `/sdcard/Android/data/package/` and to the app specific folder on `secondary external storage` i.e `/extSdcard/Android/data/package/` and with `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` you can write to all locations on `primary external storage` i.e. `/sdcard/` but you can't write to any location on `secondary` `external storage` (except app specific folder).

Answer (score 0):

so i must create a folder with the name of the package of my application but in the code of my application i must do a change or not ? this is my code

```
    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);



}

/**
 * Helper method to access the camera returns null if it cannot get the
 * camera or does not exist
 *
 * @return
 */
private Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera camera = null;
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // cannot get camera or does not exist
    }
    return camera;
}

PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();

        if (pictureFile == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            pictureFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

};

    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyCameraApp/");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            mediaStorageDir.mkdir();
        }
        return mediaStorageDir;
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    return true;
}


private String currentDateFormat(){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss");
    String  currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    return currentTimeStamp;
}
```

}